# Sequelize - return normalized data

Tags: sequelize.js

Sequelize seems to denormalize returned data. Here, a `user` is embedded within a `task`:

```
[{
  "name": "A Task",
  "id": 1,
  "userId": 1,
  "user": {
    "name": "John Doe",
    "id": 1
  }
}]
```

---

However, I find normalized data to be much easier to deal with (especially in cases of deeply nested objects), and I'd like to avoid using normalizr if possible.

Is it somehow possible to ask sequelize to return normalized data?

---

An example of desired data:

```
{
  "tasks": {
    "1":{
      "id": 1,
      "name": "A Task",
      "user": 123
    }
  },
  "users": {
    "123":{
      "name": "John Doe",
      "id": 123
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: can you show an example of a desired normalization based on the data above?

Comment: @Anatoly  Added it to the main post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sequelize can't do such normalization. You should request all tasks and then get users in a separate query getting their id's from retrieved tasks.
In SQL if you join tasks and users tables you also will get duplicated users for some tasks if they have the same user.

```
task_id,user_id,user_name
1,1,'John Dow'
2,1,'John Dow'
3,2,'John Smith'
```